# read the data from a text file which contain multilple data

Tags: python, string

I want to read a particular data of a day from a text file which contain multiple days of data. what should i do for that? that file contains strings too.

i just open the file and print the data of particular row and column. but it can't convert the string to float. It shows couldn't convert the string into float64.

data look like

```
 43371 Thiruvananthapuram Observations at 00Z 04 Mar 2023
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
        hPa     m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      956.0     64   24.2   13.2     50  10.07    105      2  301.2  331.2  303.0
      928.0    323   21.8   11.8     53   9.45     97      4  301.3  329.5  303.0
      904.0    551   21.8   10.8     50   9.07     90      7  303.6  330.9  305.2
      877.0    813   19.0    9.0     52   8.28     82      9  303.3  328.3  304.8
      869.0    891   19.0    7.4     47   7.47     80     10  304.1  326.8  305.5
      846.0   1121   19.0    2.6     33   5.47    105     17  306.4  323.5  307.5
      820.0   1389   19.0   -3.0     22   3.76    114     22  309.2  321.2  309.9
      819.0   1400   17.8    0.8     32   4.98    114     22  308.0  323.7  309.0
      810.0   1494   17.4    8.4     55   8.61    118     24  308.6  335.1  310.2
      803.0   1567   16.9    8.2     57   8.56    120     25  308.8  335.2  310.4
      708.0   2628    8.8    5.1     78   7.84    112     20  311.2  335.7  312.7
      679.0   2974    8.4    3.0     69   7.02    110     18  314.4  336.8  315.8
      669.0   3097    8.2    2.2     66   6.75    103     16  315.6  337.2  316.9
      644.0   3408    5.5    0.0     68   5.99     85     12  316.0  335.3  317.1
      618.0   3746    2.6   -2.3     70   5.26    104     16  316.4  333.4  317.4
      596.0   4038    1.1   -3.4     72   5.00    120     20  318.0  334.3  318.9
      580.0   4257    0.0   -4.3     73   4.82    121     19  319.1  335.0  320.1
      557.0   4581   -0.7  -13.7     37   2.40    123     18  322.0  330.3  322.5
      539.0   4842   -2.7  -14.8     39   2.27    125     17  322.7  330.6  323.1
      537.0   4872   -2.9  -14.9     39   2.25    121     16  322.8  330.6  323.2
      518.0   5157   -2.7  -23.7     18   1.10     81      8  326.4  330.4  326.6
      508.0   5310   -4.0  -24.5     19   1.04     60      4  326.6  330.5  326.9
      474.0   5853   -8.5  -27.5     20   0.85                327.6  330.7  327.7
      410.0   6963  -15.1  -36.1     15   0.43                332.9  334.6  333.0
    Station information and sounding indices
                                 Station number: 43371
                               Observation time: 230304/0000
                               Station latitude: 8.48
                              Station longitude: 76.95
                              Station elevation: 64.0
                                Showalter index: 9.33
                                   Lifted index: 6.19
        LIFT computed using virtual temperature: 5.83
                                        K index: 23.27
                             Cross totals index: 8.43
                          Vertical totals index: 24.01
                            Totals totals index: 32.44
          Convective Available Potential Energy: 0.00
                 CAPE using virtual temperature: 0.00
                          Convective Inhibition: 0.00
                 CINS using virtual temperature: 0.00
                         Bulk Richardson Number: 0.00
              Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV: 0.00
      Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 282.71
    Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 795.29
       Equivalent potential temp [K] of the LCL: 330.19
         Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 301.85
                  Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 9.52
    Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 30.51

43371 Thiruvananthapuram Observations at 00Z 05 Mar 2023
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1006.0     64   25.6   22.7     84  17.61      0      0  298.2  349.6  301.4
 1004.0     81   26.4   17.4     58  12.61     30      1  299.2  336.2  301.5
 1000.0    116   26.4   17.4     58  12.66     90      2  299.6  336.8  301.8
  964.0    440   25.8   16.8     58  12.64     86      8  302.1  339.7  304.4
  955.0    522   25.0   16.7     60  12.65     85     10  302.1  339.7  304.4
  931.0    745   22.8   16.3     67  12.67    100     12  302.0  339.7  304.3
  925.0    802   22.2   16.2     69  12.68    100     13  302.0  339.7  304.3
  868.0   1350   18.1   14.2     78  11.84     85     12  303.3  338.7  305.5
  850.0   1531   16.8   13.5     81  11.57     95     12  303.7  338.4  305.8
  814.0   1899   14.2   11.3     83  10.43    106     19  304.8  336.2  306.7
  770.0   2365   12.6    8.5     76   9.15    120     29  307.9  335.9  309.6
  700.0   3165    9.8    3.8     66   7.23    105     17  313.3  336.2  314.7
  692.0   3261    9.8    3.8     66   7.32    105     16  314.3  337.5  315.7
  689.0   3296    9.5    3.7     67   7.27    105     15  314.4  337.5  315.8
  658.0   3674    6.8    2.1     72   6.84     70     11  315.5  337.3  316.8
  623.0   4123    3.5    0.4     80   6.35     95      6  316.7  337.1  317.9
  620.0   4163    3.2    0.2     81   6.30     92      6  316.8  337.1  318.0
  591.0   4550    1.0   -2.8     76   5.30     67      6  318.6  335.9  319.6
  574.0   4785    1.2   -9.8     44   3.18     52      6  321.5  332.3  322.1
  525.0   5496   -3.7  -13.7     46   2.54      6      6  323.9  332.7  324.4
  520.0   5571   -2.9  -22.9     20   1.17      1      6  325.8  330.0  326.0
  500.0   5880   -5.5  -24.5     21   1.06    340      6  326.3  330.1  326.5
  467.0   6410  -10.5  -23.5     34   1.24                326.5  331.0  326.7
  455.0   6611   -9.7  -32.7     13   0.54                329.9  332.0  330.0
  446.0   6765  -10.3  -39.3      7   0.29                331.1  332.2  331.1
Station information and sounding indices
                             Station number: 43371
                           Observation time: 230305/0000
                           Station latitude: 8.48
                          Station longitude: 76.95
                          Station elevation: 64.0
                            Showalter index: 2.06
                               Lifted index: 1.99
    LIFT computed using virtual temperature: 1.45
                                SWEAT index: 192.01
                                    K index: 29.80
                         Cross totals index: 19.00
                      Vertical totals index: 22.30
                        Totals totals index: 41.30
      Convective Available Potential Energy: 0.00
             CAPE using virtual temperature: 0.00
                      Convective Inhibition: 0.00
             CINS using virtual temperature: -315.28
 Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature: 466.48
             LFCT using virtual temperature: 468.72
                     Bulk Richardson Number: 0.00
          Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV: 0.00
  Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 288.26
Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 860.18
   Equivalent potential temp [K] of the LCL: 338.49
     Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 300.95
              Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 12.74
              1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5764.00
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 44.38
```

i want the output like the following and write into a fie

```
1006.0     64   25.6   22.7     84  17.61      0      0  298.2  349.6  301.4
 1004.0     81   26.4   17.4     58  12.61     30      1  299.2  336.2  301.5
 1000.0    116   26.4   17.4     58  12.66     90      2  299.6  336.8  301.8
  964.0    440   25.8   16.8     58  12.64     86      8  302.1  339.7  304.4
  955.0    522   25.0   16.7     60  12.65     85     10  302.1  339.7  304.4
  931.0    745   22.8   16.3     67  12.67    100     12  302.0  339.7  304.3
  925.0    802   22.2   16.2     69  12.68    100     13  302.0  339.7  304.3
  868.0   1350   18.1   14.2     78  11.84     85     12  303.3  338.7  305.5
  850.0   1531   16.8   13.5     81  11.57     95     12  303.7  338.4  305.8
  814.0   1899   14.2   11.3     83  10.43    106     19  304.8  336.2  306.7
  770.0   2365   12.6    8.5     76   9.15    120     29  307.9  335.9  309.6
  700.0   3165    9.8    3.8     66   7.23    105     17  313.3  336.2  314.7
  692.0   3261    9.8    3.8     66   7.32    105     16  314.3  337.5  315.7
  689.0   3296    9.5    3.7     67   7.27    105     15  314.4  337.5  315.8
  658.0   3674    6.8    2.1     72   6.84     70     11  315.5  337.3  316.8
  623.0   4123    3.5    0.4     80   6.35     95      6  316.7  337.1  317.9
  620.0   4163    3.2    0.2     81   6.30     92      6  316.8  337.1  318.0
  591.0   4550    1.0   -2.8     76   5.30     67      6  318.6  335.9  319.6
  574.0   4785    1.2   -9.8     44   3.18     52      6  321.5  332.3  322.1
  525.0   5496   -3.7  -13.7     46   2.54      6      6  323.9  332.7  324.4
  520.0   5571   -2.9  -22.9     20   1.17      1      6  325.8  330.0  326.0
  500.0   5880   -5.5  -24.5     21   1.06    340      6  326.3  330.1  326.5
  467.0   6410  -10.5  -23.5     34   1.24                326.5  331.0  326.7
  455.0   6611   -9.7  -32.7     13   0.54                329.9  332.0  330.0
  446.0   6765  -10.3  -39.3      7   0.29                331.1  332.2  331.1
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to how your text file looks?

Comment: i put the data in inte question

Comment: @LIKHITHGOPINATH, can you **explicity** show your exact expected output (*based on the given text file*) ?

Comment: @Timeless yeah...i put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

It depends on format of your text file. If each day occupies the whole line, you can read file line by line. Next you can split your line by whitespaces and take that column you needed.
For example:
you have a text file, every string is formatted like this:
   
Then it will looks like this:

```
file = open("filename.txt", "r")
for i in file:
    line = i.split()
    print(float(line[3]))
file.close()
```

This will display all numbers from third column.

If you want to check if you can convert your string to float, you can use either try-except statement or regular expressions. Try-except looks better:

```
try:
    print(float(line[3]))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Please, specify your question, add more details

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combo *regex/pandas* with [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) to handle the missing values in some cols :

```
import re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas
​
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    splits = re.findall(r".*?(\d{2}\s*\w+\s*\d{4})$\n\s*-+\n(.*?)(?=Station)",
                        f.read(), flags=re.S|re.M)
dfs = {}
for table in splits:
    pairs = [col.split() for col in table[1].split("\n")[:2]]
    col_names = [f"{x[0]} ({x[1]})" for x in zip(pairs[0], pairs[1])]
    dfs[table[0]] = (pd.read_fwf(StringIO(splits[0][1]), header=None,
                                 names=col_names, skiprows=3, delim_whitespace=True))
​
df = (pd.concat(dfs)
          .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").reset_index(level=0, names="date")
          .assign(date= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["date"], format="%d %b %Y"))
          .set_index("date")
     )

#df.to_csv("new_file.txt", sep="\t") #uncomment this line to make a fresh csv/text file
#df.to_excel("file.txt") #uncomment this line to make an Excel spreadsheet
```

Output :

```
print(df)

            PRES (hPa)  HGHT (m)  TEMP (C)  ...  THTA (K)  THTE (K)  THTV (K)
date                                        ...                              
2023-03-04       956.0        64      24.2  ...     301.2     331.2     303.0
2023-03-04       928.0       323      21.8  ...     301.3     329.5     303.0
2023-03-04       904.0       551      21.8  ...     303.6     330.9     305.2
...                ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
2023-03-05       508.0      5310      -4.0  ...     326.6     330.5     326.9
2023-03-05       474.0      5853      -8.5  ...     327.6     330.7     327.7
2023-03-05       410.0      6963     -15.1  ...     332.9     334.6     333.0

[48 rows x 11 columns]
```

To ask for the data of a specific year/month/day or full-date, you can use [*partial string indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) :

```
df.loc["2023"] #year 
df.loc["2023-03"] #year-month
df.loc["2023-03-04"] #year-month-day
```

To go further, you can [`pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) the relationships in each table :

```
import seaborn as sns #pip install seaborn

sns.pairplot(df.loc["2023-03-04"].reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:, :3]) #first 3 columns
```

[image]